# onPress() not working on expo v42.0.0. Using TouchableOpacity for the rounded button

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, mobile-application

I used useState hook. onSubmitEditing i.e. pressing enter the command setTmpItem should run and should set the value of inputBox in the variable tmpItem.
addSubject prop passed is also a hook, which can be seen in 2nd code(app.js)

But when I press the RoundedButton, it is not console logging neither 1 nor 2 and also addSubject(tmpItem) not working.

Focus.js below

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import { RoundedButton } from '../../components/RoundedButton';

export const Focus = ({ addSubject }) => {
  const [tmpItem, setTmpItem] = useState(null);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Text> What would you like to focus on? </Text>
        <View>
          <TextInput
            onSubmitEditing={({ nativeEvent: { text } }) => {
              setTmpItem(text);
            }}
          />
          <RoundedButton
            size={50}
            title="+"
            onPress={() => {
              console.log("1");
              addSubject(tmpItem);
              console.log("2");
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

App.js below

```
//App.js is the central point to glue everything
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Focus } from './src/features/focus/Focus';

export default function App() {
  const [focusSubject, setFocusSubject] = useState(null);
  return (
    <View>
      {focusSubject ? (
        <Text>Where am I going to build a timer</Text>
      ) : (
        <Focus addSubject = {setFocusSubject}/>
      )}
      <Text>{focusSubject}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

RoundedButton.js below

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export const RoundedButton = ({
  style = {},
  textStyle = {},
  size = 125,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{props.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Comment: I am using expo v42.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle your `TextInput` for `Focus.js` by passing the `value` and `onChangeText` props in `TextInput` component like:

```js
export const Focus = ({ addSubject }) => {
  const [tmpItem, setTmpItem] = useState(null);

  const onSubmit = () => {
     //and handle this onSubmit function the way you want to
     //or pass the addSubject props
     addSubject(tmpItem);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Text> What would you like to focus on? </Text>
        <View>
          <TextInput
            onChangeText={setTmpItem}
            value={tmpItem}
            onSubmitEditing={() => onSubmit()}
          />
          <RoundedButton
            size={50}
            title="+"
            onPress={() => {
              addSubject(tmpItem);
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Also, the reason why `console.log` not working in `RoundedButton` is, you're not passing that `onPress` prop to your `TouchableOpacity` of `RoundedButton`. In `RoundedButton.js` do it like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export const RoundedButton = ({
  style = {},
  textStyle = {},
  size = 125,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>
        <Text>{props.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

`props.onPress` is what you're missing.
Hope this works for you.

Comment: I am not trying to submit on pressing enter.
I am trying to store the value entered in <TextInput> in a variable tmpItem, and then when I press the rounded button addSubject works.

Comment: I did console.log(tmpItem), and I found, on pressing RoundedButton, values are not logging. I used console.log() above and below addSubject(tmpItem) within onPress().

Comment: onPress={() => {
              console.log(tmpItem);
              addSubject(tmpItem);
              console.log(tmpItem);
            }}